# Using computed properties on page load

Tags: ember.js

First, my current versions:

```
Ember      : 2.8.1
Ember Data : 2.8.1
jQuery     : 3.1.1
```

I'm using query params in a controller. If a user goes to `assignments?strm=1292`, the `strm`, computed `term,` and computed `filteredClusters` will be called. However, the `filteredClusters` will be empty on the initial page load (e.g. I navigate to `/assignments?strm=1292` using my browser). It is only after the `selectStrm` action is called to update the `strm` query param that `filteredClusters` will start returning results.

My `assignments` index controller is listed below:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['strm', 'cluster', 'title'],
  strm: null,
  cluster: null,
  title: null,

  term: Ember.computed('strm', function() {
    var strm = this.get('strm');
    var terms = this.get('model.terms');

    return strm ? terms.filterBy('strm', strm)[0] : null;
  }),

  filteredClusters: Ember.computed('term', 'model', function() {
    var term = this.get('term');
    var clusters = this.get('model.clusters');

    if(term) {
      return clusters.filter( (cluster, index, clusters) => {
        var terms = cluster.get('terms');

        return terms.mapBy('strm').includes(term.get('strm'));
      });
    } else {
      return clusters;
    }
  }),

  actions: {
    selectStrm: function(strms) {
      var strm = strms[0];
      this.set('strm', strm);
    }
  }
});
```

What can I do to get `filteredClusters` loaded on the initial page load?

Thank you for any and all information.

Comment: Try defining `queryParams: { strm: { refreshModel: true },cluster: { refreshModel: true },title: { refreshModel: true } }` in routes/assignments.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is that `filteredClusters` has the wrong dependencies. If `model` is available, are you sure that `model.clusters` and `terms` on each cluster is already loaded? Is something a async relationship?

Probably you would need a CP dependency like `model.clusters.@each.terms.@each.strm`. However this will *not work* since a double `@each` is not supported.

For now lets assume you have three models: `assignment`, `cluster` and `term`:

*assignment*

```
clusters: DS.hasMany('cluster')
```

*cluster*

```
terms: DS.hasMany('term')
```

*term*

```
strm: DS.attr()
```

now how to get rid of this double-`@each`? The answer is simple: Have a CP on the assignment that returns all terms of all clusters:

*assignment*:

```
terms: Ember.computed('clusters.@each.terms', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'clusters')
      .map(c => get(c, 'terms'))
      .reduce((a,b) => [...a, ...b], []);
  }
}),
```

and now you can use `model.terms.@each.strm` as a dependency key for `filteredClusters`. This will force the CP to recompute when the clusters or terms are loaded.